# Executing a Dataprep template with Dataflow API holds the timestamp included in the flow recipe

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I have a cloud function which uses the dataflow API to create a new job from a template I created using DataPrep. The recipe basically cleans up some JSON objects, turn them into CSV format, and add a timestamp column to fetch everything in a BigQuery database. The main idea is to take a snapshot of certain information of our platform.

I managed to run the job from the dataflow API, and the data is correctly inserted in the bigquery table, however in the timestamp field, the value of the timestamp is always the same, and it corresponds to the execution time from the job where I take the template from(DataPrep template). When I run the job from the dataprep interface, this timestamp is correctly inserted, but it is not changed when I execute the job with the same template from the cloud function.

The snippet of code which calls the dataflow API:

```
dataflow.projects.templates.launch({
   projectId: projectId,
   location: location,
   gcsPath: jobTemplateUrl,
   resource: {
     parameters: {
       inputLocations : `{"location1" :"gs://${file.bucket}/${file.name}"}`,
       outputLocations: `{"location1" : "${location2}"}`,
       customGcsTempLocation: `gs://${destination.bucket}/${destination.tempFolder}`
     },
      environment: {
        tempLocation: `gs://${destination.bucket}/${destination.tempFolder}`,
        zone: "us-central1-f"
     },
     jobName: 'user-global-stats-flow',

   }
 }
```

This is the Dataflow execution console snapshot, as it can be seen the latest jobs are the ones executed from the cloud function, the one in the bottom was executed from the Dataprep interface:

[Dataflow console snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vttW.png)

This is the part of the recipe in charge of creating the timestamp:

[Dataprep recipe sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG2Sv.png)

Finally this is what is inserted in the BigQuery table, where the first insertion with the same timestamp (row 4) corresponds to the job executed from Dataprep, and the rest are the executions from the cloud function with the Dataflow API:

[Big Query Insertions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9XR3.png)

So the question is whether there is a way I can make the timestamp to get resolved during the job execution time for the insertion, because now it looks like it is fixed in the template's recipe.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this timestamp a parameter to your job? Did you write the template pipeline? Can you share the code? I am wondering if you are using a pipeline option to determine the timestamp, most pipeline options are backed in once the template is created, unless they are written with a ValueProvider. That's one theory, but I would like to see the template pipeline code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The timestamp is created by the recipe with the Now function. I didn't create the pipeline, it is created by dataprep itself when running the recipe on dataflow. So I dont really have access to the template creation source code.

Comment: @ÁngelRamos hi Angel, how did you export the dataprep (dataflow) job and use it as a template? Right click on the dataflow job and export it as a json, upload it into the storage and run it as a custom template?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Massimo, just in the dataprep execution screen, click on the three dot icon and click on export results, there, you can copy the GCS path to the template. You can add the prefix gs:// to that path to make use of it from the Dataflow API. You can use the snippet at the first post of this thread. The tricky part here is to use the proper parameters to invoke the template, you can check those this time from the Dataflow job’s execution screen (the one you see the flow diagram). Hope it helps

Comment: @ÁngelRamos yeah! I was able to find it in the dataprep GCS storage!
Thanks a lot, this empowers dataprep a lot more, I now can add triggers to google functions and trigger the dataflow jobs as soon as the correct files are uploaded to GCS! ;)

Comment: If this question was resolved, could you share the answer? If not, does the [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#current_timestamp) function of BigQuery help? It will insert to the table the timestamp when the rows arrives, which is very close to the processing time.

Comment: I opened the issue in the issue tracker and it has been assigned internally to the proper team, but never heard of it again, here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111023170 . As per the bq function, i would need to try as the value is fixed at the dataprep side, I am not sure if bigquery will interpret the function or will take it as string.

Comment: GCP Support here. That shouldn't happen; I'll get somebody to look at that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is documented behaviour. From the list of [known limitations when running a Dataprep template through Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Run-Job-on-Cloud-Dataflow_99745844):

> All relative functions are computed based on the moment of execution. Functions such as NOW() and TODAY are not recomputed when the Cloud Dataflow template is executed.